# Import Csv file to database Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

In my database, I have a Metadata table. I save some data in this table after extracting Meta data from different file.

My table Metadata have multiple column(to suporting all type of files).
I used Apache Tika to extract metdata and save them on csv file.

the result of extraction of metadata is not seem from file pdf to another

Example:

```
01.pdf
"dcterms:modified","meta:creation-date","meta:save-date","dc:creator","Last-Modified","dcterms:created","Author","date","modified","creator","xmpTPg:NPages","Creation-Date","title","meta:author","created","producer","Content-Type","xmp:CreatorTool","resourceName","Last-Save-Date","dc:title"
"xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx",.... // here the value of metadata

02.pdf // 
"meta:creation-date","dcterms:modified","meta:save-date","dcterms:created","Last-Modified","date","modified","xmpTPg:NPages","Creation-Date","created","producer","Content-Type","xmp:CreatorTool","resourceName","Last-Save-Date"
"xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx",.... // here the value of metadata
```

the header of metadata from 01.pdf file is not like from 02.pdf file.
There are different order!!
My table Metadata have more columns for fields in csv file.
When i use this sql query to insert data in my table some column not take extact value from csv file!!

```
 String sql1="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'"+FormatStrWithBackSlash(fValueMetadata)+"\' INTO \
            TABLE edocx_metadatafile FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS \
             (`dcterms:modified`,`meta:creation-date`,`meta:save-date`,`dc:creator`,\
              `Last-Modified`,`dcterms:created`,`Author`,`date`,`modified`,`creator`,`xmpTPg:NPages`,`Creation-Date`,  \
              `title`,`meta:author`,`created`,`producer`,`Content-Type`,`xmp:CreatorTool`,`resourceName`,`Last-Save-Date`,`dc:title`)";
```

So, How to match correctly the field in my csv file to the column in mytable metadata?

Comment: If your export does produce a different order by different exports then you could use the first line of the csv-file to create your `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement.

Comment: you mean i could not ignore my first Row??

Comment: Your `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement got to ignore the first row. But before you execute this, read just the first line with your programming language (could be C#) to create the column list of the statement. It can't be fixed because every file has its own order as you said.